# Do we want to start creating tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Any obvious tag synonyms the community thinks we can create yet?

I have privilege to create tag synonyms, so we don't need to bother Community managers and can start forming these if the community so wishes.

Who wants some synoyms?

---

One suggestion per answer, so each can be voted separately (as suggested by Monica in comments)

Comment: One suggestion per answer, please, so people can vote up/down.

Comment: Skippy could be a synonym of pushy or know it all :P

Answer (score 6):

[teeth](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teeth) should be made a synonym of [dental-care](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dental-care).

Answer (score 3):

[bathing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathing) should be made a synonym of [grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming).

Answer (score 3):

[nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) should be made a synonym of [diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet).

Answer (score 3):

[introducing-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introducing-pets) synonym of [socializing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socializing); while IP is a very specific situation, more often than not, it's an aspect of socializing.

Answer (score 1):

[grooming](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grooming) should be made a synonym of [hygiene](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hygiene), since grooming is a subset of hygiene.

Comment: Hygiene could cover the cleanliness of the water in a fish tank, but "grooming" doesn't really cover that.

Comment: Or how often to clean the cage for any number of small animals: hamsters, geckos, gerbils, frogs, stick insects. It can refer to keeping the pet in a hygienic environment, not just cleaning the pet itself.

Comment: @starsplusplus yes, the *words* have distinct nuances of meaning, but that doesn't necessarily mean they need two tags.  Is it likely that someone will be interested in only questions that deal with hygiene, but not grooming? Vice versa? That should be the criteria for whether they are made synonyms.

Comment: I was disagreeing with `since the tag wiki on grooming clearly covers hygiene`. IMO it doesn't. The examples I gave would clearly be covered by the *hygiene* tag but **not** by the *grooming* tag. There may well be, on the other hand, a case for all grooming-tagged questions being covered by the *hygiene* tag.

Comment: Either that or abolish *hygiene* altogether and have two subtags: *grooming* (referring to cleaning the animal) and *environment-cleaning* (referring to cleaning the cage/tank) - hopefully with something a bit less cumbersome for the latter, but you get the idea.

Comment: @starsplusplus The tag wiki, at the time I wrote this, was what is quoted in my answer. I'm not sure "keeping your pet clean" doesn't include the pet's environment. We do have an [tag:enclosure] tag. Perhaps using [tag:hygiene] by itself would work for grooming and hygiene questions regarding the *pet*, and [tag:hygiene] combined with [tag:enclosure] or [tag:bedding] would cover the other types of hygiene you raised?  I think perhaps you are right that grooming is a subset of hygiene, not the other way around, and I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[cleaning](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning), which was used by me for cleaning a dog, is mostly being used for fishtank maintenance.  In that sense, it is too broad a tag and should be discouraged.  I would synonymize it with [maintenance](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) to distinguish it.

Comment: I like this, but really am at a loss where to put it

Comment: Or maybe deleted as overly broad / unclear?

Answer (score 1):

[spider](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider) should be [spiders](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spiders) based on our plural rules, but since [spider](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider) exists, the system cancelled the creation of [spiders](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spiders).

Comment: I removed the spider tag, it will die overnight, and then the new spiders tag can be created. I did this with all the tortoise posts, and retagged them, without people continually rolling back the edits :p

Comment: Hey Josh, I wanted to tell you I appreciate your edits on my posts.. you've made a lot of improvements cheers :) *came here to tell you looks left* O<O *looks right* O>O

Answer (score -2):

[longevity](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/longevity) should be made a synonym of [aging](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aging).

Comment: I'm not sure we need longevity at all, but if we do I agree it should be a synonym.

Comment: I think for the time being, it might be a good idea to keep `longevity`, as it is an issue for owners (we hate to see our pets die); it's got a slightly different emphasis to `aging`, which is why I vote keep it and agree, under the synonym `aging` as it's too specific on it's own.

Comment: @Skippy Can you explain what you consider the difference between longevity and aging to be?

Comment: @beo longevity is the expected lifespan and what may or may not affect this. As opposed aging, growing older. Similar, but different concepts

Comment: @Skippy I'm having a hard time imagining many questions on longevity (aside from "how can I maximize the lifespan of *x*", which seems a bit too broad). Seems a bit too granular to me, imo, but I can't vote for or against my own answers :)

Comment: @beo  no worries  :-) I hope people don't think I mind. Most of my suggestions are just that and sometimes they're things others have mentioned and I'm really not fussed either way. I don't know who made the longevity tag. Sorry took me so long to reply. Got lost in the pings

Comment: @beo I thought it was my answer BA haha. Can you edit it and I'll reverse my up vote for you, as I'm really not fussed

Comment: @Skippy That's the whole point of meta... everything is a suggestion until enough people vote for it :)  I've made an edit for you.

Comment: @beo in case you haven't noticed I'm good at stating the obvious  haha

Answer (score -3):

[diet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) should be made a synonym of [nutrition](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

**EDIT:** Note that I have posted the reverse order as a separate option

Comment: It should go the other direction; nutrition is one aspect of diet.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I posted a [different answer](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/280/do-we-want-to-start-creating-tag-synonyms/363#363) here to reflect the opposite direction. I see your point, and upon further reflection, I tend to agree with you, but since 2 people upvoted this already, I thought it best to present both options and see which the community prefers.

Comment: Beofett, yup, makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

The [eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) and [drinking](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drinking) should both be made synonyms of [feeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeding).  Neither are broad enough to merit their own tag.

Comment: While I upvoted this yesterday, I put some thought to this and I disagree now. Eating and drinking describe an action initiated by the pet, while feeding describe an action initiated by the owner. [See my post here](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/a/328/58).

Comment: "Feeding" can refer to self-feeding, as well as feeding initiated by the owner, if we're going strictly by the definition of the word. Regardless, I don't see the functional need for separate tags. Are people really going to want to search for/hide/favorite only questions related to drinking if the pet is drinking fluids not provided by the owner?  Are there even going to be a significant number of questions that could be tagged that way? It seems way too granular. However, I will edit so you can reverse your vote.

Comment: We already have some questions about cats eating bugs and dogs hunting spiders, however they have not been tagged this way. I agree that this might be too granular, but I wanted to make my voice my thoughts. Thanks for the edit, I'll retract my upvote for now.